# Tooltip doesn't let me type text when it is appeared. IDEA's editor

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, intellij-17

I am working with **Itellij IDEA (2017.2.4)**. I am not sure whether the reason is new version of **IDEA**, but I started to face it after new version installed.

When I type some code in editor and Tooltip is shown (it can be inspection or just parameters of method shown ect.) I cannot type new symbols until pressing *ESCAPE* button, it is not useful for me. Before updating the IDEA there was behavior when user types new code, tooltip is hidden without *ESCAPE* pressing. It was made hidden by any key pressed.

Actually maybe I just change some setting property unconsciously, if yes - what is the property needed to be restored to default?

How to make it hidden not by *ESCAPE* but by any button?

In next image I pictured the moment when only *ESCAPE* key can be pressed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce the issue, even when I use v2017.2.4 on windows. The behavior should be that you can still type even when the tooltip is present:

[image: Sceenshot GIF of typing while tooltip is open]

I can't think of anything in terms of settings that could *cause* this issue. If it's just the "parameter info" tooltip that is causing the issue, you can disable it (or just increase the delay time) from automatically popping up via the setting: *Settings > Editor > Code Completion > "Parameter Info" > "Autopopup"* You can then manually open it via the Parameter Info Action via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. The setting @Maciej-Białorucki mentioned will effect the time before other tooltips open. Setting to a high value might help if other tooltips are causing issues.

Personally, I find the auto popup useful. To troubleshoot why this is causing issues, I'd recommend trying the following:

1. Upgrade to v 2017.2.6 which was released yesterday. While I personally can't reproduce it, and I'm not seeing anything about it in the [2017.2.5 Release Notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2017.2.5+Release+Notes) nor the [2017.2.6 Release Notes](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2017.2.6+Release+Notes), it can't hurt to try and upgrade.
2. Disable all third party plugins and restart IDEA. See if the issue persists. In my 14 years of using IDEA and helping people with it on the forums, I've seen 3rd party plugins having bugs that cause other parts of IDEA to misbehave. Since you recently upgraded, it's possible a 3rd party plugin is having a compatibility issue with the new version. If the disabling them solves it, use a binary search to as you re-enable the plugins to track down the culprit and then report the bug to the plugin's developer.
3. See if it happens in other projects. If not there may be something wrong with the project's configuration. (A long shot. But worth checking out)
4. As another long shot, you can try invalidating the caches and then restarting IDEA via *File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...* I have on occasion over the years seen a corrupted index file or cache cause strange behavior.
5. If none of the above work, I suggest opening a bug report with JetBrains at: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: @Eugene Stepanenkov I see I cross posted my answer with yours. Glad you found the issue. Looks like is it an known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-182128 that was reported earlier this morning.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, yep I found the solution, see my answer.

Comment: and actually the same think reproduced on a latest version of Intellij IDEA 2017.2.6

Comment: Sounds like it got introduced in 2017.2.4 if it started happening to you after you upgraded to it. Hopefully now that its been reported it can be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Check *Tooltip initial delay(ms)* option under *Appearance* in Idea settings.

Comment: it is 1200 ms now

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Maciej, but changing delay cannot help me.

Answer (score 0):

As I divined there was a property in settings that influences to the behavior described in a question. So to continue writing code without pressing *ESCAPE* key you must uncheck the following property:

Menu page **Settings** -> **Appearance & Behavior** -> **System Settings**

Checkbox **Accessibility** -> **Support screen readers (requires start)**

(for more details see [the link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/system-settings.html#d789070e190))